# GIT - push a new branch into an existing github account

Tags: git, github

We have a git project with old references, that don't exist anymore.

I want to push this repository into a new branch on my github of that project.https://github.com/rubo77/ffmap-d3

I thought the best way is creating a new branch and push that branch into my github:

```
git branch ffki
git checkout ffki
```

How do I push that branch into my github?

my `.git/config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git://github.com/toppoint/ffmap-d3.git
    pushurl = git@github.com:toppoint/ffmap-d3.git
[remote "rubo77"]
    url = https://github.com/rubo77/ffmap-d3.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/rubo77/*
```

Answer (score 1):

You should type:

```
$ git push origin ffki
```

This will create the "ffki" branch remotely, with all your new changes on it.

If you want to push it to "rubo77":

```
$ git push rubo77 ffki
```

Comment: thanks, the `git push rubo77 ffki` worked. How do I make this default for `git push`?

Comment: You probably don't want to do that.  You probably want to keep "git push origin master" the default for git push because ideally, you will only be working on this branch for a period of time.

Comment: So then how do I change the origin to my github-acount? the current origin is wrong

Comment: $ git remote rm origin; git remote add origin git@github.com:<your-github-username>/<the-project-name>.git (At least for Github.)

Comment: [`git config branch.ffki.remote rubo77`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html). <-- that config link is a good one to spend some time with, git has lots of settings, some of which don't have commandline options.